# Easiest way to determine versions of spring dependencies to replace with when updating spring boot to 3?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am updating from Spring boot 2 (actually 2.6.6) to Spring Boot 3, and there are a lot of hardcoded version numbers in my pom.xml that will need to be updated, but of course I don't know what to replace the hardcoded versions to (for example spring-security, jdbc, etc)

if I generate a spring boot 3.0 project from start.spring.io, is there an easy way to do this by looking at the resulting jars to determine what versions go with the change in the version number of spring-boot-starter-parent?

Comment: The easiest way is to just not hardcode the version numbers and let the Spring Boot Maven plugin do its job.

Comment: That said, here is the curated list of dependencies that the current Spring Boot version is known to be compatible with (these versions will be picked up automatically by the Maven plugin if you omit their version numbers): https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/dependency-versions.html

Answer (score 2):

Use the [versions-maven-plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions/versions-maven-plugin/index.html) to figure out what new versions are available (use [display-dependency-updates](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions/versions-maven-plugin/display-dependency-updates-mojo.html)).

I would recommend updating them all to the latest release versions.